# How to deploy a react server-side application

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack

I was working on a project that rendered the react component on the express server running and then delivers the html from the server side.
The project consist of two webpack configs file one for the client(react code) and other for the server sending the resolved react code.

But I am facing issue on how to deploy this application.
[Diretory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbH0N.png)

Project contains two webpack files one for the express server and other for the client side code(ReactJs).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.